# Toast not showing at the right time

Tags: android

On the click of a button I want to show a Toast Message while there is some work being done but even through I have it at the start the toast is not being shown until the end

```
if (id == R.id.edit_score_button_update) {

Toast.makeText(this, "Updating please wait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Some code that update database

finish();
```

What is the best way to force the toast to be shown first. Thanks for your time

Comment: You may performing operation that block the UI thread(Example. Performing netwok operation etc) , so Toast won't show up utill UI thread is free

Comment: try to use an asyncTask for your network operation or your database update, and display your Toast in the `onPreExecute()`

Comment: wouldnt a while loop have that effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a class inside your activity class that extends `AsyncTask`.

```
UpdateDBTask task = new UpdateDBTask();
task.execute(someString);
```

In your async task you define 3 variables - (All can't be primitive: meaning `int` for example has to be `Integer`).

First is what you send to the async task object to use in `doInBackground()`.
 Second is what you use to update your main thread with `onProgressUpdate()`.
Third is what `doInBackground()` returns, and `onPostExecute()` will get and use to show results (again - in main thread). You don't have to use any of them (LIke in the code I gave you), but you have to write something as types when extending `AsyncTask`.

```
public class UpdateDBTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Everything written here will happen in main thread before doInBackground() starts.
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Do your things in different thread, allowing the main
        //thread change things on GUI (Like showing toast...)
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Everything you do here happens in the main thread AFTER doInBackground() is done.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. that did it. Works better now do not need to Toast at all and its done in the background